# SimpleXML - how to?

Tags: android, retrofit2, simple-framework

I have been trying for a couple days to get SimpleXML to work with Retorfix and parse an xml response from NOAA. The data comes from the following url: https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1.5&stationString=KOJA

I keep getting errors regarding the METAR field:

> onFailure: NOAA: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=, required=true) on field 'metar' private us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.data.noaa.METAR us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.data.noaa.Data.metar for class us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.data.noaa.Data at line 9

I have tried changing the field type from METAR to String and back. I've tried different annotations. I can't figure out what the issue is.

For brevity I will only list the classes I feel important here:

```
package us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.data.noaa;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class Response {

@SerializedName("errors")
@Expose
private String errors;

@SerializedName("time_Taken_ms")
@Expose
private String time_taken_ms;

@SerializedName("Data_Source")
@Expose
private Data_source data_source;

@SerializedName("Request")
@Expose
private Request request;

@SerializedName("Request_Index")
@Expose
private String request_index;

@SerializedName("Data")
@Expose
private Data data;

@SerializedName("Warnings")
@Expose
private String warnings;

@SerializedName("version")
@Expose
private String version;

public Response() {
    /* Empty Constructor */
}

public String getErrors ()
{
    return errors;
}

public void setErrors (String errors)
{
    this.errors = errors;
}

public String getTime_taken_ms ()
{
    return time_taken_ms;
}

public void setTime_taken_ms (String time_taken_ms)
{
    this.time_taken_ms = time_taken_ms;
}

public Data_source getData_source ()
{
    return data_source;
}

public void setData_source (Data_source data_source)
{
    this.data_source = data_source;
}

public Request getRequest ()
{
    return request;
}

public void setRequest (Request request)
{
    this.request = request;
}

public String getRequest_index ()
{
    return request_index;
}

public void setRequest_index (String request_index)
{
    this.request_index = request_index;
}

public Data getData ()
{
    return data;
}

public void setData (Data data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

public String getWarnings ()
{
    return warnings;
}

public void setWarnings (String warnings)
{
    this.warnings = warnings;
}

public String getVersion ()
{
    return version;
}

public void setVersion (String version)
{
    this.version = version;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [errors = "+errors+", time_taken_ms = "+time_taken_ms+", data_source = "+data_source+", request = "+request+", request_index = "+request_index+", data = "+data+", warnings = "+warnings+", version = "+version+"]";
}
}
```

Data Class:

```
package us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.data.noaa;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;

public class Data
{
@SerializedName("num_result")
@Expose
@Attribute(required = false)
private String num_results;

@SerializedName("METAR")
@Expose
@Attribute(required = true)
private METAR metar;

@SerializedName("meta")
@Expose
@Attribute(required = false)
private String meta;

public void setMeta(String meta) {
    this.meta = meta;
}

public String getMeta() {
    return meta;
}


public String getNum_results ()
{
    return num_results;
}

public void setNum_results (String num_results)
{
    this.num_results = num_results;
}

public METAR getMetar ()
{
    return metar;
}

public void setMETAR (METAR metar)
{
    this.metar = metar;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [num_results = "+num_results+", metar = "+ metar +"]";
}
}
```

METAR Class:

```
package us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.data.noaa;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class METAR
{
@SerializedName("sea_level_pressure_mb")
@Expose
private String sea_level_pressure_mb;

@SerializedName("wind_dir_degrees")
@Expose
private String wind_dir_degrees;

@SerializedName("altim_in_hg")
@Expose
private String altim_in_hg;

@SerializedName("observation_time")
@Expose
private String observation_time;

@SerializedName("temp_c")
@Expose
private String temp_c;

@SerializedName("visibility_statute_mi")
@Expose
private String visibility_statute_mi;

@SerializedName("flight_category")
@Expose
private String flight_category;

@SerializedName("maxT_c")
@Expose
private String maxT_c;

@SerializedName("raw_text")
@Expose
private String raw_text;

@SerializedName("sky_condition")
@Expose
private Sky_condition[] sky_condition;

@SerializedName("minT_c")
@Expose
private String minT_c;

@SerializedName("dewpoint")
@Expose
private String dewpoint_c;

@SerializedName("metar_type")
@Expose
private String metar_type;

@SerializedName("wind_speed_kt")
@Expose
private String wind_speed_kt;

@SerializedName("three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb")
@Expose
private String three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb;

@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private String longitude;

@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private String latitude;

@SerializedName("station_id")
@Expose
private String station_id;

@SerializedName("elevation_m")
@Expose
private String elevation_m;

@SerializedName("quality_control_flags")
@Expose
private Quality_control_flags quality_control_flags;


public String getSea_level_pressure_mb ()
{
    return sea_level_pressure_mb;
}

public void setSea_level_pressure_mb (String sea_level_pressure_mb)
{
    this.sea_level_pressure_mb = sea_level_pressure_mb;
}

public String getWind_dir_degrees ()
{
    return wind_dir_degrees;
}

public void setWind_dir_degrees (String wind_dir_degrees)
{
    this.wind_dir_degrees = wind_dir_degrees;
}

public String getAltim_in_hg ()
{
    return altim_in_hg;
}

public void setAltim_in_hg (String altim_in_hg)
{
    this.altim_in_hg = altim_in_hg;
}

public String getObservation_time ()
{
    return observation_time;
}

public void setObservation_time (String observation_time)
{
    this.observation_time = observation_time;
}

public String getTemp_c ()
{
    return temp_c;
}

public void setTemp_c (String temp_c)
{
    this.temp_c = temp_c;
}

public String getVisibility_statute_mi ()
{
    return visibility_statute_mi;
}

public void setVisibility_statute_mi (String visibility_statute_mi)
{
    this.visibility_statute_mi = visibility_statute_mi;
}

public String getFlight_category ()
{
    return flight_category;
}

public void setFlight_category (String flight_category)
{
    this.flight_category = flight_category;
}

public String getMaxT_c ()
{
    return maxT_c;
}

public void setMaxT_c (String maxT_c)
{
    this.maxT_c = maxT_c;
}

public String getRaw_text ()
{
    return raw_text;
}

public void setRaw_text (String raw_text)
{
    this.raw_text = raw_text;
}

public Sky_condition[] getSky_condition ()
{
    return sky_condition;
}

public void setSky_condition (Sky_condition[] sky_condition)
{
    this.sky_condition = sky_condition;
}

public String getMinT_c ()
{
    return minT_c;
}

public void setMinT_c (String minT_c)
{
    this.minT_c = minT_c;
}

public String getDewpoint_c ()
{
    return dewpoint_c;
}

public void setDewpoint_c (String dewpoint_c)
{
    this.dewpoint_c = dewpoint_c;
}

public String getMetar_type ()
{
    return metar_type;
}

public void setMetar_type (String metar_type)
{
    this.metar_type = metar_type;
}

public String getWind_speed_kt ()
{
    return wind_speed_kt;
}

public void setWind_speed_kt (String wind_speed_kt)
{
    this.wind_speed_kt = wind_speed_kt;
}

public String getThree_hr_pressure_tendency_mb ()
{
    return three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb;
}

public void setThree_hr_pressure_tendency_mb (String three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb)
{
    this.three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb = three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb;
}

public String getLongitude ()
{
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude (String longitude)
{
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getLatitude ()
{
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude (String latitude)
{
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getStation_id ()
{
    return station_id;
}

public void setStation_id (String station_id)
{
    this.station_id = station_id;
}

public String getElevation_m ()
{
    return elevation_m;
}

public void setElevation_m (String elevation_m)
{
    this.elevation_m = elevation_m;
}

public Quality_control_flags getQuality_control_flags ()
{
    return quality_control_flags;
}

public void setQuality_control_flags (Quality_control_flags quality_control_flags)
{
    this.quality_control_flags = quality_control_flags;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [sea_level_pressure_mb = "+sea_level_pressure_mb+", wind_dir_degrees = "+wind_dir_degrees+", altim_in_hg = "+altim_in_hg+", observation_time = "+observation_time+", temp_c = "+temp_c+", visibility_statute_mi = "+visibility_statute_mi+", flight_category = "+flight_category+", maxT_c = "+maxT_c+", raw_text = "+raw_text+", sky_condition = "+sky_condition+", minT_c = "+minT_c+", dewpoint_c = "+dewpoint_c+", metar_type = "+metar_type+", wind_speed_kt = "+wind_speed_kt+", three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb = "+three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb+", longitude = "+longitude+", latitude = "+latitude+", station_id = "+station_id+", elevation_m = "+elevation_m+", quality_control_flags = "+quality_control_flags+"]";
}
}
```

NOAAWeather Class

```
package us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.noaaweather;

import org.simpleframework.xml.convert.AnnotationStrategy;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlConverterFactory;

public class NOAAWeatherClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
   OkHttpClient.Builder OkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

   HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
   logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
   OkHttpClient.addInterceptor(logging);


    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(
                        new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy())))
                .client(OkHttpClient.build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

NOAAWeatherService Class

```
package us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.noaaweather;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.data.noaa.Response;

public interface NOAAWeatherService {
// dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1.5&stationString=KBIL

@GET("httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1.5")
Call<Response> getMetar(@Query("stationString") String icao);

}
```

ApiUtil Class

```
package us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network;

import us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.avwx.AVWXClient;
import us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.avwx.AVWXService;
import us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.geocodexyz.GeoCodeXYZClient;
import us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.geocodexyz.GeoCodeXYZService;
import us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.noaaweather.NOAAWeatherClient;
import us.sensornet.aviationweatherapp.network.noaaweather.NOAAWeatherService;

public class ApiUtil {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://avwx.rest/api/";
public static final String NOAA_BASE_URL = "https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/";
public static final String GEOCODE_BASE_URL = "https://geocode.xyz/";

public static AVWXService getAVWXService() {
    return AVWXClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(AVWXService.class);
}

public static NOAAWeatherService getNOAAWeatherService() {
    return NOAAWeatherClient.getClient(NOAA_BASE_URL).create(NOAAWeatherService.class);
}

public static GeoCodeXYZService getGeoCodeService() {
    return GeoCodeXYZClient.getClient(GEOCODE_BASE_URL).create(GeoCodeXYZService.class);
}
}
```

I had included the URL for the API with the exact request I am making. I've tried to included it here but I either get a format error or it rips out the the xml tags. So follow the link above and you'll see the exact response I am getting. Thank you for taking a look at this:

I am now seeing multiple METAR items in the results. Something I didn't seen when testing the API in a browser before coding. This may be an issue. However, please look at this and let me know if there are other issues. I think I can simply make a List in the Data model?`enter code here`

Comment: It might be in the data.  Post a sample response from the URL that fails.  My suspicion is the input doesn't have a metar field or it isn't named metar( probably named meta) so the required annotation fails.

Comment: There is both a metar and meta field. meta is for meta data about the request and metar is aviation weather data.

Comment: For those who land here: In my case the issue was that in some circumstances the API was returning a list of METAR objects. Simply converting the data type to a list or array didn't solve the problem and continued to give that same error. However, changing the annotations by adding: @ElementLIst(entry="METAR", inline=true) solved my issue.

Comment: @user693336 The convention here is that if you solve your own problem you can [post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That way, it shows up as "Answered" in search results, and the answer is more visible than in one of these little comments, which are intended to be temporary notes for clarifying details. Glad you got it working! :)